Are there other solutions to the functional equation $f(x^t) = t f(x)$ besides logarithms?
Are there other solutions to the functional equation $f(x^t) = t f(x)$ besides logarithms? Here $x$ and $t$ are real variables with $x>0$.
I know that given the property of logarithms $\log(x^t) = t\log x$ that these functions fulfill the functional equation.
But I don't know if there are any other solutions to the functional equation $f(x^t) = t f(x)$ (or equivalently to $f(x^{1/t}) = \frac{f(x)}{t}$), maybe some that don't fulfill the equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. I hope you could give explicit examples in this case.

trivial but . $f(x)=0  \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x^n)=nf(x)=0$

@AntonyTheo Thanks. I have to be more explicit next time about looking for solutions other than the trivial zero function.

Let $u=x^n$ and $v=x^m$. Then if $f(x^n)=n f(x)$ for all $n$, it follows that $f(u)=n f(x)$, $f(v)=n f(x)$, and thus $f(uv)=(n+m) f(x)=f(u)+f(v)$. So it seems like this functional equation is just as strong as the usual one. (The caveat is that this may be too cavalier with these variables' domains.)

Is $n$ restricted to integers?

We have a Set of Solutions with Parameter $c$ [[ $f(x) = c \log x$ ]] $c = 1$ is normal : $c = 0$ is Constant function which @AntonyTheo gave : $c = -1$ is a reflection : All $c$ values will work.

@RobertIsrael no, $n$ could be real-valued

If $n$ can be real-valued, then $f$ is completely determined on $(0,\infty)$ by a single value $f(x_0)$ with $x_0\ne1$, and so it's easy to show that $f(x) = c\log x$ with $c=f(x_0)/\log x_0$.

@GregMartin Let me see If I have understood: what you are saying is that for continuous $n$ the only real-valued solution of $f(x^n)=nf(x)$ are logarithms?

yes that's right

@GregMartin If that is true, could you state it as an answer in order to close the question please?

Yes, but I must first edit the question to remove the confusion about whether $n$ (now $t$) is integer-valued or real-valued.

Suppose that $f(x^t) = t f(x)$ for all $x>0$ and all $t\in\Bbb R$. In particular, $f(x) = f(e^{\log x}) = (\log x)f(e)$ for all $x>0$. Therefore $f(x)$ must be a logarithm function, namely $f(x) = \log_bx$ with $b=e^{1/f(e)}$. (One exception: if $f(e)=0$ then $f(x)=0$ identically.)
